# Rails: overwriting concern methods in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have a basic set of methods across a number of models. To do that, I've extracted the methods to a concern. So:

```rb
module Userable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def invoices
    Invoice.none
  end
end

class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  include Userable
end

class Broker < ApplicationRecord
  include Userable

  has_many :invoices
end
```

However, it seems that the method defined in `Userable` is taking precedence over the `has_many` relation in the `Broker` class. So running something like `broker.invoices` returns `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` when I would actually want the `has_many` relation to take precedence. Is this feasible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defined?` in your `concern` code to not override your scopes in model.

```rb
module Userable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  unless defined? :invoices
    def invoices
      Invoice.none
    end
  end
end

Broker.invoices.count
# => # real count e.g. 10

Agent.invoices.count
# => 0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I am getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'invoices'` response

Comment: please give more information. How do you call it? From Broker model, from Agent model

Comment: I call it form `agent.invoices`. If I remove the `unless defined? :invoices` as suggested, then it works. I think that `unless defined? :invoices` is not properly checking if the model contains that method. Instead, it is only checking the concern. Something like that

Comment: I think there is something else in your code, that I cannot see in your question example. My example will not allow invoices to not be defined. They will be defined even before this module included, otherwise it will define it by the included module Userable. Make sure you including module, but not extending your class. If you will check it on very simple example like you gave in original question, it **will work**. So I think there's something around